# jsdom - how to set an element dataset?

Tags: jsdom

I am using jsdom to create the `window.document` object and pass it into a function that is being tested. However, after creating an new element I cannot set the `dataset` property:

```
var my = function(document){
    var item = document.createElement('a');
    gridItem.tabIndex = 1;
    gridItem.dataset.num = 1;
};
```

The error I get when running my test is:

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'num' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
element.setAttribute("data-foo","bar");
```

instead of

```
element.dataset.foo = "bar";
```